# How do I upload a CSV file to R with one row that contains a list in the form of ["123", "456", "789"]?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to upload a CSV file that has various data in normal format (column name and then either numeric or string) as well as a column that has a list of numbers of various length in ["x"] format (i.e. row 1 = ["111", "222"], row 2 = ["333"], row 3 = ["555","666","777"]. How do I upload that data so that I can conduct analysis with it?

When I turned it into a character string, the data came back as "[\"x\"]". When I turned it into a factor, it looked like the format in the CSV. But I still can't do anything with the [" present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use the `stringr` package to grab the digits out of the square brackets. I think the reason `\` shows up is because it is used as an escaping character to escape the second set of `""`. Anyways, this will simplify it,

I made some ugly data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3),
                 y = c('[\\"111\\", \\"222\\"]', '[\\"333\\"]', '[\\"555\\", \\"666\\", \\"777\\"]'))
df
  x                                 y
1 1            [\\"111\\", \\"222\\"]
2 2                       [\\"333\\"]
3 3 [\\"555\\", \\"666\\", \\"777\\"]
```

Now just using some regex from and `stringr::str_extract_all` we grab all occurrences of 1 or more digits in succession.

```
df$y <- stringr::str_extract_all(df$y, "(\\d+)")
```

`(\\d+)` is simply saying I want to grab groups of 1 or more digits.

This yields a nested list without the `\` included.

```
  x             y
1 1      111, 222
2 2           333
3 3 555, 666, 777
```

They are still strings, so if you want to evaluate the numbers you need to do stuff like:

```
> eval(parse(text = df$y[[1]][1])) / 111
[1] 1
```

For the whole data frame you may consider unnesting it and making a new column (or overriding the original to change the data type and turn the strings into evaluate(able) expressions, For this we can use some of the `tidyverse` (`tidyr::unnest` and `dplyr::mutate`)

```
df %>% 
  tidyr::unnest() %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(numeric_y = eval(parse(text = y))) 

# A tibble: 6 x 3
      x y     numeric_y
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1 111         111
2     1 222         222
3     2 333         333
4     3 555         555
5     3 666         666
6     3 777         777
```

Comment: This is perfect!! Thank you :)

Comment: Follow-up question: what do I do if some rows have no data (i.e.: [""]). It just gets rid of those rows. Also, lets say I'm at the point of code at the end of your post and I have another column with similar ["x"] data. How can I split that up so that it adds even more rows to my data frame rather than only show data with values?

Comment: Do you want to keep blank entries or convert them to NA?
You should be able to apply the same logic to many columns and then `unnest` the whole thing.

Comment: I added 0 to the original file and then it worked.. But how would I convert them to NA? Also is unnest the same as ungroup?

Comment: `unnest` is not the same as ungroup. A dataframe can be seen as a list of lists and so when you have one column in the data frame made up of other lists unnesting will sort of unlist these.

Comment: If you added 0 and it worked, you could convert all 0 to NA with a `gsub`.